# find the limits $\lim_{x \to 2}\dfrac{f(-x)+3}{f(x-4)+1}=?$

Tags: calculus

> Let : $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \ \ \ : |f(2x)-1|<(x+1)^2$
>   Then find the limits :
>
> $$\lim_{x \to 2}\dfrac{f(-x)+3}{f(x-4)+1}=?$$

My Try :

$$|f(-2)-1|<0\\ 0<f(-2)<+1 $$

now :

$$\lim_{x \to 2}\dfrac{f(-2)+3}{f(-2)+1}=?$$

now what ?

Comment: I think the inequality should be $\le$ rather than $<$.

Answer (score 0):

$$|f(2x)-1|<(x+1)^2\Longrightarrow 1-(x+1)^2<f(2x)<1+(x+1)^2$$
so we have $f(-2)=\lim_{x\to -1} f(2x)=1$ and then
$$
\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{f(-x)+3}{f(x-4)+1}=\frac{f(-2)+3}{f(-2)+1}=2
$$

Comment: There is no need to know $f(-2)$ just knowing the limit at $-2$ is sufficient.